# Repair status not 100% after repair

Tags: cassandra

I have noticed that some tables show less than 100% "Percent repaired" in the `nodetool tablestatus` output. I have manually executed repairs on all nodes (3 node cluster, RF=3) but the value doesnt seem to change.

Example output:

```
           Table: users
            SSTable count: 3
            Space used (live): 66636
            Space used (total): 66636
            Space used by snapshots (total): 0
            Off heap memory used (total): 688
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.5731829674519404
            Number of partitions (estimate): 162
            Memtable cell count: 11
            Memtable data size: 483
            Memtable off heap memory used: 0
            Memtable switch count: 27
            Local read count: 120833
            Local read latency: NaN ms
            Local write count: 12094
            Local write latency: NaN ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Percent repaired: 91.54
            Bloom filter false positives: 0
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom filter space used: 568
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 544
            Index summary off heap memory used: 112
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 32
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 30
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 1916
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 420
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): NaN
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): NaN
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
            Dropped Mutations: 0
```

Repair was done with `nodetool repair -pr`

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Percent repaired` seems to be a misleading metric as it refers to the percentage of SSTables repaired, but there are some conditions to be computed here:
 - the tables should not be from systems keyspaces
 - the tables should have a replication factor greater than 1
 - the repair should be incremental or full (non-subrange)

When you use `nodetool repair -pr`, that will invoke a full repair that won't be able to update this value.

For more information regarding incremental repairs, I would recommend [this article](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/12/14/should-you-use-incremental-repair.html) from the Last Pickle. Since they adopted the maintenance of the reaper tool, they have become an authority regarding repairs.

Comment: Thanks. So to sum it up - incremental repairs are not recommended now. Primary range repairs do not update the repair stats - is it best to use "nodetool repair" for now? This should be enough to run only on one node.

Answer (score 2):

Executing `nodetool repair -pr` will repair the primary range owned by the node that command is executed on.

What does this mean?  The node this command is executed on has data that it "owns", i.e., its primary range, but the node also contains data/replicas "owned" by other nodes.  You are not repairing the replicas "owned" owned by other nodes.

Now, if you execute that command on every single node in the cluster (not data center), it will cover all the token ranges.

EDIT / NOTE:
My answer did not properly address the question.  Although what I wrote is accurate, the answer to the question is stated in the answer above mine; basically, the percentage repaired is a value that is for incremental repair usage and is not affected by a full repair.  (Incremental repair marks the repaired ranges as it works so it does not spend time re-repairing later.)

Comment: If you execute that on all nodes, and have zero data incoming to the cluster, confirm the repairs have completed, then all the data would be repaired.  Is that the scenario?

Comment: No, see above - the repairs finished on all 3 nodes, but the users table still shows a repair ratio < 100.an even smaller table is remaining at <60%

Comment: What version of C*?

Comment: Ok, the naming of the value is misleading as it is intended for incremental repairs.  I would expect the name to be revised in the future to avoid confusion.